The work-energy theorem in a resistor
A basic model for a resistor is a conductor with ions and sea of electrons. If a current is flowing through this resistor, then an electric field must be present inside it. If the left hand side of the conductor is at a high potential and the right hand side at lower potential, then the electric field will be directed from left to right. Applying the work energy theorem to a charge $q$ moving from $a$ to $b$, gets us:
$$W_{ab}=U_{a}-U_{b}$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{W_{ab}}{q}=V_{a}-V_{b}$$
Another fact says that the charge $q$ moves at constant speed, namely the drift speed. However, applying the same work energy theorem dictates an increase in the kinetic energy.
Firstly, how can I reconcile this fact with the work energy theorem?
Secondly, why does the decrease in energy in the resistor seem to be entirely taken care of by stating that charge is moving in the electric field, where is the energy lost due to collisions with ions?
Thinking about it a little more got me to noticing the following:
When I said "applying the work-energy theorem dictates an increase in the kinetic energy", I forgot to notice that the electric force isn't the only force in action. For the sake of the argument, I can assume the existence of a non-conservative resistive force to take care of the occurring collisions. Taking the previously stated fact into consideration, I will assume the resistive force to be equal to the electric force. Doing this, the net work done will be zero. Therefore, no increase in the kinetic energy is require. The decrease in potential energy is lost to the work done by the non-conservative resistive force saving the conservation of energy. Is my analysis right?

Doesn’t look like the work energy theorem to me. Simply looks like the definition of potential difference

You need to be careful about the "level" you are looking at, since technically all interactions will be conservative if you are considering electrons interacting with other charged particles.

In future you might save yourself a lot of head scratching by first stating the system that you are considering which in this case is an electron.  Having done that you need to identify the external forces acting on the system which you have done using you after thoughts which give the answer to your original query.

The work energy theorem states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy. Note my emphasis on net.
The reason the kinetic energy does not increase is the resistance does negative work equal to the positive work done by the electric field for net work of zero.
The mechanical analog of the resistance is kinetic friction.
Hope this helps.
